# How set port jmeter in jmeter 4 and 5?

Tags: jmeter, port, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

I run two tests of two different machines, the first one runs the second is KO,
can you explain why I have two different ports (4446 and 4445) at each test launch?

The first test is OK:
Creating summariser  t / TU_27h35.csv -e -o / report / TU_27_02 Created the tree successfully using /home/ouitead/scriptsJmeter/TdC_15012019/all_tu.jmx
Starting the test @ Wed Feb 27 15:49:06 CET 2019 (1551278946720)
Waiting for possible Shutdown / StopTestNow / Heapdump message on port 4446
summary + 15 in 00:00:25 = 0.6 / s Avg: 869 Min: 504 Max: 1296 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 2 Started: 8 Finished: 6
summary + 19 in 00:00:30 = 0.6 / s Avg: 527 Min: 185 Max: 868 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 15 Finished: 14
summary = 34 in 00:00:55 = 0.6 / s Avg: 678 Min: 185 Max: 1296 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 8 in 00:00:30 = 0.3 / s Avg: 704 Min: 151 Max: 1963 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 1 Started: 18 Finished: 17
summary = 42 in 00:01:25 = 0.5 / s Avg: 683 Min: 151 Max: 1963 Err: 0 (0.00%)
summary + 8 in 00:00:24 = 0.3 / s Avg: 344 Min: 206 Max: 619 Err: 0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 20 Finished: 20
summary = 50 in 00:01:49 = 0.5 / s Avg: 629 Min: 151 Max: 1963 Err: 0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ... @ Wed Feb 27 15:50:56 CET 2019 (1551279056488)
... end of run

The second test is KO:
Created the tree successfully using /scriptsJmeter/all_tu.jmx
Starting the test @ Wed Feb 27 15:50:10 CET 2019 (1551279010436)
Waiting for possible Shutdown / StopTestNow / Heapdump message on port 4445
summary = 0 in 00:00:00 = ****** / s Avg: 0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err: 0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ... @ Wed Feb 27 15:51:59 CET 2019 (1551279119074)
... end of run

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Port 4445 is controlled by property [jmeterengine.nongui.port](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html#stop) and increment port number in case port is used (by another execution for example)

> JMeter CLI mode will listen for commands on a specific port (default 4445, see the JMeter property jmeterengine.nongui.port). JMeter supports automatic choice of an alternate port if the default port is being used (for example by another JMeter instance). In this case, JMeter will try the next higher port, continuing until it reaches the JMeter property jmeterengine.nongui.maxport) which defaults to 4455.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why the second test is in error (no call was sent)?

Comment: @Sami need more info, show how you execute jmeter and add your test plan, maybe you are missing other property, see also jmeter log